# index page not under public_html?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

As I reinstalled my theme, I created a folder installed under the public folder. Here I uploaded all the installation files for the new theme. This went as a new Magento installation and not just adding files to an existing Magento. I was hoping, I could install the new Theme + Magento into the public_html folder but instead it was all installed under the "install" folder. Now my the site only works under "mydomain/install/" while I want "mydomain" only. How can I correct this? Should this be done at the back end under CMS Home pages?

Comment: No.. It can be done by pointing your domain name to `../public_html/install`. Change the DocumentRoot in your vhost file

Comment: This sound to me the fasted way but how to do this? Before doing this is it first possible to rename the install folder to my domain name, just for the cosmetics and than change the Vhost file? But where to find this file?

Comment: @GirishSH please add that as an answer. Preferably with an example vhost snippit. It's a good one

Comment: @Sander Ok Sure, I will add it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the files from the install folder to the root folder via FTP.

The only thing you need to change after that is the table rows with path `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in the `conre_config_data` database  table. These should be the value **http://domain.com/** instead of  **http://domain.com/install/**

Comment: I have tried this but this doesn't work unless there is a missing link. As soon when you move all files via ftp you don't get access anymore to your back-end and can't edit the database table. I still sees the Mydomain/install/ path where it expects the index file to be. I than reversed and before I move via FTP I first changed the database secure and unsecure. Also that didn't work.

Comment: Hm either there are several base_url fields or the baseurl is hardcoded in `app/etc/local.xml`, your htaccess or index.php

Comment: This was not a good idea as now I cant get anymore to my back-end and change the base-url back to install. Seems like I have to delete all and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Point your domain name to `../public_html/install/` instead of `../public_html`

For that you need to change the DocumentRoot in your vhost file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /path_to_your_public_html/public_html/install/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In the above code, You need to change the DocumentRoot line.

If you are using the cPanel, In addon Domains options you can find the settings :
As shown below

[image]

Comment: I believe you want to say point your domain to ../public_html/ instead of ../public_html/install/ Now what is the document root? I assume I have to edit this file. Where is that file located?

Comment: No.. You should change it to `../public_html/install/` from `../public_html/`.. Which OS you have in server?

Comment: apache. Yes I can create it as a subdomain at the Cpanel. So the new Domain name will be mydomain and the sub domain mydomain/install. is that correct?